# Django Python Template Nested List using For Loop

Tags: python, django, api, for-loop, django-templates

i'm really new to python programming. Please help me how to show the following result to my template:

The Result That I Would like to have in my Django Template is the following example below in a table view:

```
Up Devices          Down Devices
Server-01           Server-02
Server-03

Total 2             Total 1
```

I am connecting to a server with API. Here is an example of the API result via GET:

```
{
    "treesize": 10,
    "devices": [
          {
            "objid": 3222,
            "objid_raw": 3222,
            "device": "Server-01",
            "status": "Up",
            },
          {
            "objid": 3291,
            "objid_raw": 3291,
            "device": "Server-02",
            "status": "Down",
        },
          {
            "objid": 3357,
            "objid_raw": 3357,
            "device": "Server-03",
            "status": "Up",
        },
    ]
}
```

Here is my views.py. Please correct me if this is the best way to get the info that I wanted.

```
response = requests.get('sample_api_url')
data = response.json()

up_devices = dict()
for device in data['devices']:
    if device['status'] == "Up":
        device_info = {
            "objid" : device['objid'],
            "device" : device['device'],
            "status" : device['status'],
        }
        objid = device['objid']
        up_devices[objid] = device_info
    else:
        device_info = {
            "objid" : device['objid'],
            "device" : device['device'],
            "status" : device['status'],
        }
        objid = device['objid']
        down_devices[objid] = device_info

context = {
    'treesize': data['treesize'],
    "up_devices": up_devices,
}

return render(request, 'monitoring/dashboard.html', context)
```

My List results is

```
{
    3222: {'objid': 3222, 'device': 'Server-01', 'status': 'Up'},
    3291: {'objid': 3291, 'device': 'Server-02', 'status': 'Up'},
    3357: {'objid': 3357, 'device': 'Server-03', 'status': 'Up'},
}
```

However, I do not know how to parse it in my template, I can only get the Key and not the values. Example:

```
<table>
    {% for key in up_devices %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ up_devices }}</td>
            <td>{{ up_devices.key.device }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using dictionary.items():

```
<table>
    {% for key, value in up_devices.items %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ value.device }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

That should give you the device value.

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish in the views file, but there's a lot of duplication that you can cut down on by moving everything out of the `if, else` clauses except the assignments that change, ie.

```
for device in data['devices']:
    device_info = {
        "objid" : device['objid'],
        "device" : device['device'],
        "status" : device['status'],
    }
    objid = device['objid']
    if device['status'] == "Up":
        up_devices[objid] = device_info
    else:
        down_devices[objid] = device_info
```

Answer (score 0):

`up_devices` is a dictionary, not a list. You can access dictionary keys and values at the same time by using the `items` method on the dictionary object.

```
<table>
    {% for key, value in up_devices.items %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ key }}</td>
            <td>{{ value.device }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```